# well, I fell for the sugardaddy scam

Tags: united-states, internet, banking

So, long of the short. They offered to pay off my meager credit card debt. I was able to cancel all the payments but one.

I called my bank and reported a fraudulent payment. It was for $211.
So, am I going to jail or will the charge reverse and I pay my bills like usual?

I know I made a mistake, please don't rub it in.

Comment: No idea what exactly the “sugardaddy” scam is, and you shouldn’t come here for true legal advice... but there’s almost certainly zero chance of you going to jail.

Comment: @A.fm. Oh, I understand. I'm just sort of trying to calm my anxieties.

Basically, someone offers you their bank account number to pay off any debt, but it ends up being fraud. I hadn't gotten to the point where the scammer reverses the charge or asks for any gift cards or anything. So, I was just caught in a moment of weakness.

The bank said they would investigate the charge.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://money.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BlueDogRanch i've posted there and a commenter suggested i post here. but, if this needs to be deleted, by all means.

Comment: I think this question is not "off-topic", so I am neither downvoting nor voting to close it. But you should explain the situation much more clearly, since it is hard to make sense of what happened. If the credit card debt was "meager", how is it that you eventually sought to cancel *multiple* payments? if your payments were made to the scammer, wouldn't these have sufficed to pay your actual debt (or bills) instead? what does a payment of "meager" debt have to do with the American notion of suggardaddy that you mention in the title?

Comment: This question https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/109924/am-i-being-scammed-by-a-sugar-daddy describes this kind of scam. Basically the mark is tricked into being a money-mule by a supposed wealthy older man: "Here is some money because I like your pretty eyes, and while you are at it can you also forward this much larger amount to my grandma in Lithuania?"

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you were either tricked into being a "[money mule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_mule)" or you were yourself the victim of fraud. Presumably you were sent money and asked to forward it on to someone else. In the money mule scenario this money is the product of a crime and you are helping launder it. Or this may have been the variant where the incoming payment bounces after you have sent it on, leaving you out of pocket.

As the article says, a witting money mule is complicit in the crimes being committed (generally money laundering or fraud). However if you were genuinely unaware that you were being involved in a crime then there was no intent to commit a crime ("[mens rea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mens_rea)") on your part so you are not guilty, although you may need to persuade law enforcement of this. Any messages exchanged with your "sugar daddy" are likely to help in establishing this, so make sure you keep them. You might also want to [read this](https://www.aclu.org/sites/default/files/images/resources/kyr_english.pdf) about what to do if the police want to question you. Talking to a lawyer ahead of time might be a very good idea too. Do not assume that just because the police are sympathetic and friendly that they are on your side. Being sympathetic and friendly is a very good way of getting people to incriminate themselves.

If you have simply been conned out of money then you have not committed a crime.